# How to run a Django project locally in PyCharm using HTTPS?

Tags: python, django, https, pycharm, localhost

I need to run a Python Django project with PyCharm IDE locally using HTTPS so that other services can talk with my service without errors.

I need help managing to run it locally in HTTPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `runserver_plus` extension. It depends on `Werkzeug`, so you have to install it first. Installation:

```
pip install Werkzeug
pip install django-extensions
pip install pyOpenSSL
```

Then add `django_extensions` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` inside `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
)
```

Now you need to generate self-signed certificate for your local server. Something like this, credits to [Diego Woitasen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176685/12914274):

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 365
```

And now you can run Django this way:

```
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file /path/to/cert.crt
```

And some links for sources:

- [`runserver_plus` with SSL](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/runserver_plus.html#ssl).
- [`Werkzeug` installation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/installation/).